# Calendar always shows 7:00 no matter what the data in the table says - Basically the variable is always set to 7:00

Tags: php, datetime, scripting, calendar

I have a table with data exactly like this:

```
  ID  Heading       Description  Time       Location   Start_Date  End_Date
  63  Wed Serv      Small group  19:00:00   null       2010-10-13  null
  70  Fall Harvest  Calvary      null       Pepin, Wi  2010-10-30  null
```

My Calendar shows the events on the correct dates, but the time for both events is 7:00 pm and I can't figure out why. For the one event the time is null but it's still saying 7:00 pm on the calendar.

Take a look at the variable called $time

My script is this:

```
<?php

//if the current page is empty, set the date variable to the current time, else set the date variable to the currentpage
$date = empty($_GET['currentpage']) ? time() : strtotime($_GET['currentpage']);

//This puts the day, month, and year in separate variables
$day = date('d', $date);
$month = date('m', $date);
$year = date('y', $date);
$bigYear = date('Y', $date);
$first_day = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);             //we need to generate the first day of the month
$month_name = date('F', $first_day);                        //get the current month's full spelling
$day_of_week = date('D', $first_day);                       //find out what day of the week the first day of the month falls on
$prevM = getDate(mktime(0, 0, 0, $month-1, 1, $year));      //gets an associative array of the previous month
$nextM = getDate(mktime(0, 0, 0, $month+1, 1, $year));      //gets an associative array of the next month                           
$prevMonth = "{$prevM['year']}-{$prevM['mon']}";            //gets the actual previous month's name. Subtracts the year from the month so you're not stuck in the current year.
$nextMonth = "{$nextM['year']}-{$nextM['mon']}";            //gets the actual next month's name. Subtracts the year from the month so you're not stuck in the current year.
$day_count = 1;                                             //counts the days up to 7 so we know when to start a new week
$day_num = 1;                                               //counter for the total number of days in the month
$dates = new dates();                                       //instantiate the dates object

//once we know what day of the week it falls on, we know how many blank days before it occur.
switch($day_of_week) {
    case "Sun": $blank = 0; break;
    case "Mon": $blank = 1; break;
    case "Tue": $blank = 2; break;
    case "Wed": $blank = 3; break;
    case "Thu": $blank = 4; break;
    case "Fri": $blank = 5; break;
    case "Sat": $blank = 6; break;
}

//then we need to determine how many days are in the month
$days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year);

//Here we start building the table heads 
echo "<table>".PHP_EOL;
echo "\t\t\t\t<thead>".PHP_EOL;
echo "\t\t\t\t\t<tr>".PHP_EOL;
echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t<th colspan=2 class=\"noBorder\"><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevMonth'>&laquo;</a></th>";
echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t<th colspan=3 class=\"noBorder\"><strong>$month_name"." "."$bigYear</strong></th>";
echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t<th colspan=2 class=\"noBorder\"><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$nextMonth'>&raquo;</a></th>";
echo "\t\t\t\t\t</tr>".PHP_EOL;
echo "\t\t\t\t\t<tr>".PHP_EOL;
echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t<th>Sun</th>".PHP_EOL;
echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t<th>Mon</th>".PHP_EOL;
echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t<th>Tue</th>".PHP_EOL;
echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t<th>Wed</th>".PHP_EOL;
echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t<th>Thu</th>".PHP_EOL;
echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t<th>Fri</th>".PHP_EOL;
echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t<th>Sat</th>".PHP_EOL;
echo "\t\t\t\t\t</tr>".PHP_EOL;
echo "\t\t\t\t</thead>".PHP_EOL;
echo "\t\t\t\t<tbody>".PHP_EOL;
echo "\t\t\t\t\t<tr>".PHP_EOL;

//first we take care of those blank days
while($blank > 0) 
{
    echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t<td>&nbsp;</td>".PHP_EOL;
    $blank = $blank-1;
    $day_count++;
}

//while we're not at the last day of the month...
while($day_num <= $days_in_month) 
{           
    //get the events from the table
    foreach($dates->getRows() as $results) 
{   
//parse the date field
$eventStartYear = substr($results['start_date'], 0, 4);
$eventStartMonth = substr($results['start_date'], 5, 2);
$eventStartDay = substr($results['start_date'], 8, 2);
$eventEndYear = substr($results['end_date'], 0, 4);
$eventEndMonth = substr($results['end_date'], 5, 2);
$eventEndDay = substr($results['end_date'], 8, 2);
$heading = $results['heading'];
$description = $results['description'];
$time = strftime("%l:%M %P", $results['time']);


//if the event fields are not null and the event day is equal to the day counter, and the event month and year are equal to the current month
// AND it is a multiple day event
if(!is_null($eventStartDay) && !is_null($eventStartMonth) && !is_null($bigYear) && !is_null($eventEndDay) && !is_null($eventEndMonth) && !is_null($eventEndYear) && $day_num == $eventStartDay && $month == $eventStartMonth && $bigYear == $eventStartYear)
{   
    $currentDay = $eventStartDay;

    //while the current day is less than or equal to the end day of the event
    while($currentDay <= $eventEndDay)
    {
        //echo "id = ".$id."<br />";
        //echo "time = ".$time."<br />";
        //echo "time2 = ".$time2."<br />";
        echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t<td><a href=\"displayEvent.php?id=$id\">$day_num<h4>".$heading."</h4><h5>".$time."</h5></a></td>".PHP_EOL;
        $currentDay++;
        $day_num++;
        $day_count++;
    }
 }

 if(!is_null($eventStartDay) && !is_null($eventStartMonth) && !is_null($bigYear) && $day_num == $eventStartDay && $month == $eventStartMonth && $bigYear == $eventStartYear)
 {
    //echo "id = ".$id."<br />";
    //echo "time = ".$time."<br />";
    //echo "time2 = ".$time2."<br />";
    echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t<td><a href=\"displayEvent.php?id=$id\">$day_num<h4>".$heading."</h4><h5>".$time."</h5></a></td>".PHP_EOL;
    $day_num++;
    $day_count++;

 }

 //make sure we start a new row every week
 if($day_count > 7) 
 {
     echo "\t\t\t\t\t</tr>".PHP_EOL;
     echo "\t\t\t\t\t<tr>".PHP_EOL;
     $day_count = 1;
 }
```

}

```
                        //print days that don't have events
                        echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t<td><a href=\"noEvent.php\">$day_num</a></td>".PHP_EOL;
                        $day_count++;
                        $day_num++;

                        //make sure we start a new row every week
                        if($day_count > 7) 
                        {
                           echo "\t\t\t\t\t</tr>".PHP_EOL;
                           echo "\t\t\t\t\t<tr>".PHP_EOL;
                           $day_count = 1;
                        }
                    }

                    //finish the table with some blanks if needed
                    while($day_count > 1 && $day_count <= 7) {
                        echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t<td>&nbsp;</td>".PHP_EOL;
                        $day_count++;
                    }

                    echo "\t\t\t\t\t</tr>".PHP_EOL;
                    echo "\t\t\t\t</tbody>".PHP_EOL;
                    echo "\t\t\t</table>".PHP_EOL;

                ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `$time = strftime("%l:%M %P", $results['time']);` line.  If you pass `strftime` a null value, it will default to 12:00am UTC, which in your timezone will be 7:00pm.  This is why both records show up as 7:00pm.  You should add some logic to set a default time to show up for records with unspecified times.

For example:

```
$time = $results['time'] != null ? strftime("%l:%M %P", $results['time']) : "";
```

Comment: I have this line in the header of my page `<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/Detroit'); ?>` Should i not put this at the top but rather in an if statement if the $time variable is not null?

Comment: What do you want it to show if the time is `null`?  The example above should display "12:00 am"

Comment: I want no time to show then so i just `$time = "";`if the result['time'] is null.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you pass NULL to `strftime()`? You might need to wrap an if statement around that assignment and use an empty string for null times.

If that's not the problem, I would suggest you dump your `$results['time']` value to make sure it's set to null when you think it is.